Same priority Rule execution sequence
I have 2 Rules Rule1 and Rule2 both have same salience value 100.
Want to know if both rules(rule1.drl and rule2.drl) are loaded in KieBase. Then what will be the order of evaluation of Rules when Facts are inserted in KieBase Session. and session.fireAllRules() is execution.
Will it depend on the loadOrder of the drl file means if rule1.drl is loaded first then Rule1 will be checked first and the Rule2
